# How to remove the space between the scroll bar and the border of a textarea in firefox?

Tags: html, textarea

In Firefox, when I set a textarea's style's padding, scroll bar, and border, the padding is between scroll bar and border. Is it possible to put the padding between scroll bar and the text content?

```
<textarea style="overflow: scroll; padding: 20px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem only exists on Firefox and is already a well-known problem:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157846

You can, however set `padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 20px;` to get rid of the space on the side.

Comment: It was reported 10 years ago, and still not fixed. Will it be fixed?

Comment: @EFanZh If enough people vote to fix the bug.  You can submit your vote to fix it using the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

We're in 2020 and still Mozilla only supports two properties: `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar-width`.

So, I had this same behaviour in firefox v.80.0 (64-bit) and managed to solve with `margin-right: -1px;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it using `overflow-x: hidden;` but, without use the `scroll horizontal`